# Multilines plot by Type and Label through time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataset

```
Date              Type        Label
2020-03-20         A            1
2020-03-20         A            0
2020-03-19         B            1
2020-03-17         A            1
2020-03-15         C            0
2020-03-19         A            0
2020-03-20         D            1
2020-03-20         A            1
```

I am interested in creating a figure with multiple lines, one for each `Type`, plotted through time (`Date`), selecting only those obs with `Label` equals to 1.

I tried

```
df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Type', values='y')
```

But it says:

> ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

.

Any idea on how to create a such multilines plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- first filter for **Label.eq(1)**
- it's not clear what you are trying to plot,  so have provided two
- you need to deal with fact there is a duplicate for **2020-03-20 A**

  - first plot does this through count
  - second plot by `drop_duplicates()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=[10,6])

# count over time
(df.loc[df.Label.eq(1),].groupby(["Date","Type"]).agg({"Type":"count"})
 .unstack(1).droplevel(0,axis=1)
 .fillna(method="ffill")
 .plot(ax=ax[0], kind="line")
)

# binary exist / not exist
(df.loc[df.Label.eq(1),["Date","Type"]]
 .drop_duplicates()
 .assign(vals=1)
 .pivot(index="Date", columns="Type", values="vals").fillna(0)
 .plot(ax=ax[1], kind="line")
)
```

[image]